Need help with evaluating a multivariable limit
Tried evaluating the  following limit using the squeeze theorem:
$$\lim_{(,)→(0,0)} \frac{1-\cos(xy)}{xy^2}$$
$$0 \leq f(x,y) \leq \left| \frac{1-\cos(xy)}{xy^2} \right| \leq \left| \frac{1-\cos(xy)}{xy} \right| = 0$$
so by squeeze theorem the limit should be equal to 0.
Is this correct? according to Wolfram, the multivariable limit should be equal to 0
.

The inequality is not correct left side is bigger than the right side, anyway how did you find that $|\frac{1-\cos(xy)}{xy}|$ goes to 0?

i didnt mention in the post, my bad. t = xy. \frac{1-\cos(t)}{t} = \frac{1-\cos(t)}{t} \times \frac{1+\cos(t)}{1+\cos(t)} = \frac{\sin^2(t)}{t(1+\cos(t))} = \frac{\sin(t)}{t} \times \frac{\sin(t)}{1+\cos(t)} =
I aint the best with LaTex, sorry. I don't know how to format this correctly

The limit is not well defined as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ means that $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and $x^2+y^2\to 0.$ But it does not mean that $x\neq 0$ or $y\neq 0.$ You should use $x\to 0,,y\to 0$ instead of $(x,y)\to (0,0).$

You'd prob have more luck use trig identity. $1-\cos(xy) =2\sin^2(xy/2)$

You solution is not correct since eventually $|y|<1$, as an alternative
$$\frac{1-\cos(xy)}{xy^2} =x\cdot\frac{1-\cos(xy)}{(xy)^2} \to 0 \cdot \frac12=0$$

$$\left |{1-\cos(xy)\over xy^2}\right|={\sin^2(xy)\over x^2y^2}{|x|\over 1+\cos(xy)}\le {|x|\over 1+\cos(xy)}$$ By the squeeze rule the limit is equal $0.$

We know that for $t\to 0$:
$$1 - \cos(t) \sim_0 \frac{t^2}{2}$$ and $1-\cos t\geq 0$.
If $t = xy$, being $(x,y)\to (0,0)$:
$$1 - \cos(xy) \leq \frac{(xy)^2}{2} = \frac{x^2 y^2}{2}. $$
Using this approximation, we get:
$$ 0\leq \frac{1 - \cos(xy)}{xy^2} \leq \frac{\frac{x^2 y^2}{2}}{xy^2} = \frac{x^2 y^2}{2xy^2} = \frac{x}{2}. $$
And if $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ then $x \to 0$, hence, $\frac{x}{2} \to 0$.
By the squeeze theorem:
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{1 - \cos(xy)}{xy^2} = 0. $$
